# Pie chart coloring

Tags: matlab, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart without using the command 'pie' in matlab. I have somehow managed but I have failed to color the segments. can someone help me how i can do so: below is my code:

```
function pie_chart

r = 1;
v = [10 15 20 25 30];

C = ['r' 'g' 'b' 'm' 'c'];

t= 0:0.01:2*pi;

x = r * cos(t);
y = r * sin(t);

plot(x,y, 'k');hold on

for k=1:length(v)

  t=[v/sum(v)*2*pi];

  for t=1:length(t)

    x=[0 r *cos(t)];
    y=[0 r *sin(t)];

    plot(x,y); hold on

    fill(x,y,'C');

  end

  axis square

  axis off

end
```

Comment: in `fill(x,y,'C')` - `'C'` is not a color. You probaly wanted `'c'` or `C(t)`

Answer (score 1):

There were a few errors in your code:

When you declare `C = ['r' 'g' 'b' 'm' 'c'];` you concatenate the strings between the `[]`, so you ended up with `C='rgbmc'`. It is better to declare it as a [`cell`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) array, by using the curly braces `{}`. So your declaration becomes: `C = {'r' 'g' 'b' 'm' 'c'};`

The `fill` function needs an enclosed area to fill. You were sending only 2 points coordinates to the function (so basically a line), so it was only coloring the line.

Actually, it wasn't even coloring because you were specifying `'C'` as the color. You have to send one of the string contained in your cell array of color: `C{k}`

Lastly, you do not need a double loop, a single loop over your different quadrant is enough (you were defining `t` in the outer loop, then immediately overwriting it when declaring the second loop).

The following code produces the colored pie chart. If you do not understand some aspects, I suggest you run it line by line and look at the variable content in the workspace.

```
function pie_chart

% Define quadrants and color
r = 1;
v = [10 15 20 25 30];
C = {'r' 'g' 'b' 'm' 'c'};

theta = linspace(0,2*pi,359) ;
idx_spokes = round( [1 cumsum(v)/100*length(theta) ] ) ; %// find the indices of the spokes

for k=1:length(idx_spokes)-1

   t = theta( idx_spokes(k):idx_spokes(k+1) ) ;

   x=[0 r*cos(t) 0];
   y=[0 r*sin(t) 0];
   plot(x,y); hold on
   fill(x,y, C{k} );
end

axis square
axis off
```

Comment: thanks so much. Really appreciate your effort. I see where I was getting it all wrong.

Comment: @Jesuit if this answer works for you, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the "V" icon beside it.